# OpenShift conditional Image pull

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-3

We are deploying our application to OpenShift and using YAML we specify the Image pull secret and image location.

The image location will pull the image from a artifactory located in different geo,
sometimes we observe connection issues during deployment since the region is far

Is there a way in OpenShift deployment to check that If the image is not being pulled from artifactory then pull it from a different artifactory in different region ?

I know that we can update the variable in OpenShift YAML but I am looking for a way to do it conditionally
What is the best way to achieve this